# filling the empty rows with zeros in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using R to prepare a `data.frame` which will be used in mixed-effects regression later. I'm pretty new to R, I've tried to search and find the solution for my problem but I couldn't find exactly what I want.

My `data.frame` has 20071 rows and I want to add a new column but it has a length of 1767 and I need to fill the rest with zeros. 
Here's the code:

```
data$M1 <- c(data$M1,(data$Mw[(data$Mw > 6.5)]-6.5))
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "M1", value = c(0.0999999999999996,  : 


replacement has 1767 rows, data has 20071
```

So I knew that I just need to add zeros of length of empty rows, but I couldn't find an answer in my search.

Comment: Do you want to just append those zeros at the end? Can you add a reproducible example with expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
data$M1 <- pmax(data$Mw - 6.5, 0)
```

The idea here is the following: You want to create a vector that contains `data$Mw - 6.5` unless `data$Mw < 6.5`, in which case the vector should be zero. This means that you will have zero exactly when `data$Mw - 6.5 < 0`. So, for each `i`, your vector will contain the maximum of `data$Mw - 6.5` and `0`.

This is exactly what the function `pmax()` is for: it takes multiple vectors as inputs and returns the elementwise maximum. This is easiest seen with an example:

```
pmax(c(1, 4), c(3, 2))
[1] 3 4
```

The first value of the output corresponds to `max(1, 3)` the second value to `max(4, 2)`.

This is considerably faster than using `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is extracting data that lives up to your condition (1767 rows), thus a vector that is shorter than you number of rows in your dataframe.

You should use "ifelse" instead.

```
data$M1 <- ifelse(data$Mw > 6.5,
                  data$Mw - 6.5,
                  0)
```

If the number is above 6.5 you subtract 6.5 from the number, else you return zero.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
data$M1[1768:20071] <- 0
```

or, if M1 is a separate vector or column of another data-frame:

```
data$M1 <- c(M1, rep(0, 20071-1768))
```

Comment: This answer has a problem, the OP should know beforehand the value `1768`. And please learn how to format code. I did it for you since you are a new user but it's not that hard. See on top of the answer box.

Comment: To format code, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Using `cbind.fill()` from the `rowr` library, we can bind different size dataframes/vectors while filling holes with a desired `fill`.

```
  > a=as.data.frame(matrix(0,4,2),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  > a
      V1 V2
    1  0  0
    2  0  0
    3  0  0
    4  0  0
    > b=c(1,2,3)

    > cbind.fill(a,b,fill=0)
      V1 V2 object
    1  0  0      1
    2  0  0      2
    3  0  0      3
    4  0  0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R way is to create the column filled with zeros first and then use a logical index.

```
data$M1 <- 0
data$M1[data$Mw > 6.5] <- data$Mw[data$Mw > 6.5] - 6.5
```

This is probably faster.